# Is c++ string class read only?

Tags: c++, string

```
std::string test("this is a test string");
test[0] = 'b';
```

like the code above, part of the string has been changed, will the compiler generate a new string or do the modification on the old one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`test[0]` will return a non-const (since the string object is non-const) reference to a first character which would be successfully replaced with `b` character.

Look the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/).

Answer (score 4):

No, you are modifying the old one. If you want a string object read only, you need **const**

```
std::string const test("this is a test string");
test[0] = 'b'; // compile error.
```

Comment: It worth mentioning that declaring object as `const` doesn't make it truly read-only as you state it since constness could be cast away.

Comment: @Kolyunya but it would be undefined behaviour to perform any non-const operations on it.

Comment: @juanchopanza thank you for an information, I did not know that! `7.1.5.1/4: Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.`

Comment: @Kolyunya If the original object is not `const`, then it is not UB. So you can have `void foo(const& string s1);` and `string s; foo(s);` and then do a `const_cast` inside of `foo` and call non-const methods. It would be confusing and error prone, but not UB because `s` is not `const`. So maybe some of those hacks you have seen are "OK".

Comment: @juanchopanza I see now... Thank you for an explanation. The one example I can remember is a class-member getter returning a const-reference to a non-const member. The reference constness was cast away and non-const operations were applied. And so it was perfectly legal as it comes out.

Answer (score 2):

You will modify existing `string`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) the operator[] will return a reference on the character at this index.

> If the string object is const-qualified, the function returns a const char&. Otherwise, it returns a char&.

If you string is constant you will not be able to modify it, else you will be able to change the original string

Answer (score 1):

The `test` `std::string` will become "bhis is a test string" since you can change it.
The string literal `"this is a test string"` used to construct the string will not change.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `string` will copy the character array. The second line will modify that copy.

Comment: Actually there's no string the constructor could copy; it will copy the *character array* into the newly created string.

Comment: I consider an array of `char` to be a C-style string. But, I will change the text anyways.

Answer (score 0):

C++ `std` strings are `mutable` and they are changeable. In this case, string will undergo a modification instead of instantiating a new string object.